# How do I pull album art thumbnail from Bandcamp?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm developing a program that takes a YouTube or Bandcamp link to a song and automatically pulls the associated album artwork or thumbnail.

For YouTube, it's a simple process. There is a [server](https://img.youtube.com) that returns the image. An example of a request would be the YouTube track id inserted into the link, like so:

`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${id}/mqdefault.jpg`

I am trying to find a similar method to pull album art from Bandcamp but I've had no luck. Further, the API they offer only let's you interact with your own account.

Comment: Took a quick look at their site and API, my best guess is it won't be as straightforward as YouTube, maybe you will even have to resort to scraping the image from the album page.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the track ID. To do that, you can make a request like this:

```
http://bandcamp.com/api/url/2/info?key=SECRET&url=duststoredigital.com/track/sudden-intake
```

However you need a key to use this method. I found a few keys online, but that will be up to you if you want to try to find your own. I emailed them, but it seems they aren't giving out keys any more:

```
Date: Fri, 17 Sep 2021 21:31:29 +0000
From: Bandcamp Support <support@bandcamp.com>
Subject: Re: (Case 1268890) API Access

Thanks for your interest. Our APIs are currently limited to Label Accounts
(bandcamp.com/labels) looking to pull physical order and general sales
information, though that might change down the road. Please keep an eye on
bandcamp.com/developer for updates.
```

As a workaround, you can make a request like this:

```
HEAD /track/amaris-2 HTTP/1.1
Host: schnaussandmunk.bandcamp.com
```

and in the response should be this:

```
Set-Cookie: session=1 r:["nilZ0t2809477874x1633448962"] t:1633448962; domain=.bandcamp.com
```

In this case, `t` is the `tralbum_type` and `2809477874` is the `tralbum_id`. Once you have the track ID, you can make a request like this:

```
http://bandcamp.com/api/mobile/24/tralbum_details?band_id=1&tralbum_type=t&tralbum_id=2809477874
```

In the response should be something like this:

```
"art_id": 3809045440,
```

Then you can format a URL like this:

```
http://f4.bcbits.com/img/a<ARTID>_<FORMAT>.jpg
```

Formats here:

```
height: format,
100:  3,
124:  8,
135:  15,
138:  12,
150:  7,
172:  11,
210:  9,
300:  4,
350:  2,
368:  14,
380:  13,
700:  5,
1200: 10,
1500: 1,
```

I have a package for all this, but it's in another language:

https://github.com/89z/mech